# How to detect null column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe defined with some null values. Some Columns are fully null values.

```python
>> df.show()
+---+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|  C|   D|
+---+---+---+----+
|1.0|4.0|7.0|null|
|2.0|5.0|7.0|null|
|3.0|6.0|5.0|null|
+---+---+---+----+
```

In my case, I want to return a list of columns name that are filled with null values. My idea was to detect the constant columns (as the whole column contains the same null value).

this is how I did it:

```python
nullCoulumns = [c for c, const in df.select([(min(c) == max(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).first().asDict().items() if const]
```

but this does no consider null columns as constant, it works only with values.
How should I then do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend the condition to

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import min, max

((min(c).isNull() & max(c).isNull()) | (min(c) == max(c))).alias(c)
```

or use `eqNullSafe` (PySpark 2.3):

```
(min(c).eqNullSafe(max(c))).alias(c)
```

Comment: @desertnaut: this is a pretty faster, takes only decim seconds :D

Comment: This works for the case when all values in the column are null. But consider the case with column values of `[null, 1, 1, null] `. In this case, the min and max will both equal `1` . Thus, will get identified incorrectly as having all nulls.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to do it implicitly: select each column, count its NULL values, and then compare this with the total number or rows. With your data, this would be:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

nullColumns = []
numRows = df.count()
for k in df.columns:
  nullRows = df.where(col(k).isNull()).count()
  if nullRows ==  numRows: # i.e. if ALL values are NULL
    nullColumns.append(k)

nullColumns
# ['D']
```

But there is a simpler way: it turns out that the function `countDistinct`, when applied to a column with all NULL values, returns zero (0):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

df.agg(countDistinct(df.D).alias('distinct')).collect()
# [Row(distinct=0)]
```

So the `for` loop now can be:

```python
nullColumns = []
for k in df.columns:
  if df.agg(countDistinct(df[k])).collect()[0][0] == 0:
    nullColumns.append(k)

nullColumns
# ['D']
```

**UPDATE** (after comments): It seems possible to avoid `collect` in the second solution; since `df.agg` returns a dataframe with only one row, replacing `collect` with `take(1)` will safely do the job:

```python
nullColumns = []
for k in df.columns:
  if df.agg(countDistinct(df[k])).take(1)[0][0] == 0:
    nullColumns.append(k)

nullColumns
# ['D']
```

Comment: @MehdiBenHamida Careful! `collect` here is **not** applied to the whole of your data, but to an *aggregation*. Arguably, this is a legitimate use of `collect`.

Comment: I know that collect is about the aggregation but still consuming a lot of performance :/

Comment: @MehdiBenHamida perhaps you have not realized that what you ask is not at all trivial: one way or another, you'll have to go through *all* your rows, checking for NULLs; now, if you are not happy even to use `countDistinct`... (as if `min` and `max` would take less time, if applicable)

Comment: this will consume a lot time to detect all null columns, I think there is a  better alternative. For the first suggested solution, I tried it; it better than the second one but still taking too much time. I think, there is a better alternative!

Answer (score 4):

How about this? In order to guarantee the column are *all* nulls, two properties must be satisfied:

(1) The min value is equal to the max value

(2) The min *or* max is null

Or, equivalently

(1) The min AND max are both equal to `None`

Note that if property (2) is not satisfied, the case where column values are `[null, 1, null, 1]` would be incorrectly reported since the min and max will be `1`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def get_null_column_names(df):
    column_names = []

    for col_name in df.columns:

        min_ = df.select(F.min(col_name)).first()[0]
        max_ = df.select(F.max(col_name)).first()[0]

        if min_ is None and max_ is None:
            column_names.append(col_name)

    return column_names
```

Here's an example in practice:

```
>>> rows = [(None, 18, None, None),
            (1, None, None, None),
            (1, 9, 4.0, None),
            (None, 0, 0., None)]

>>> schema = "a: int, b: int, c: float, d:int"

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rows, schema=schema)

>>> df.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|   d|
+----+----+----+----+
|null|  18|null|null|
|   1|null|null|null|
|   1|   9| 4.0|null|
|null|   0| 0.0|null|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> get_null_column_names(df)
['d']
```

Comment: If Anyone is wondering from where F comes. It is Functions imported as F |

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Comment: Good catch @GunayAnach. I updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

### Time effective: Spark> 3.1 If you have more Not Null columns compared to Null columns

Generally checking if an entire col is Null is a time intensive operation, however generally calling `isNotNull()` is faster compared to `isNull()` call on NotNull columns. The following trick with `limit()` can fasten the approach by a lot if you expect more Not Null columns compared to Null cols.

```
# col_a is a Null col
st = time.time()
print("Result:", sdf.where(sdf.col_a.isNotNull()).limit(1).count())
print("Time Taken:", time.time() - st)
# Output
# Result: 0
# Time Taken: 215.386

# col_b is a Not Null col
st = time.time()
print("Result:", sdf.where(sdf.col_b.isNotNull()).limit(1).count())
print("Time Taken:", time.time() - st)
# Output
# Result: 1
# Time Taken: 7.857
```

Where a result of 0 means it is a null col and 1 it is otherwise. Now you can   loop over all columns in the spark dataframe.